# Cartoon with a duck and pig travelling around in a spaceship

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I remember a cartoon which I watched when I was young. The main character is a duck who is the captain of a spaceship & a pig who is his assistant. The duo travel around in the spaceship but I can't remember much else.

Additional details include:

- The duck is black and his beak is yellow
- The pig is pink

Comment: thank you for this question and reminding me of this show. I feel old now, since there are people who see a black duck with yellow beak and don't automatically think "Daffy Duck"

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This sounds like [*Duck Dodgers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_Dodgers_(TV_series)) from 2003.

[image: Daffy sits in the captain's seat looking over at Porky in a side seat at a workstation who is looking worried over the back of his chair at Daffy]

The spaceship captain/hero is Daffy Duck, the sidekick is Porky Pig.

It could also be its 1953 predecessor: ["Duck Dodgers in the 24½th Century"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_Dodgers_in_the_24%C2%BDth_Century).

Comment: Seriously?  They went back and made an entire series out of that one Daffy Duck and Porky Pig spoof of "Buck Rogers?"

Comment: @JRE They did, and it's genuinely really good. They even got Tom Jones to do the theme song.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for : Duck Dodgers 2003.  Thanks !  +1 ✔

Comment: Two seasons worth, with Animaniacs and Samurai Jack style episodes.

Comment: @JRE, not entirely just that one spoof.  Duck Dodgers has appeared in a [number of Merrie Melodies/Looney Tunes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_Dodgers)

Comment: With Buck Rogers and pulp SF, the spoofs pretty much write themselves.  I suspect the problem was limiting it to only two seasons worth!

Comment: The Duck Dodgers shorts also gave us his nemesis, Marvin the Martian.

Answer (score 15):

#### [*Rocket Squad*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0049686/) (1956)

> In a futuristic city, Detectives Monday and Tuesday pursue a wanted criminal.

It's a Looney Tunes cartoon short starring Daffy Duck and Porky Pig.

[image: Daffy and Porky sit in the cockpit smoking]

Comment: Cartoon characters packing heat *and* smoking, (and littering as well) - there's something they're not allowed to do anymore.  (Also from the looks of Porky's eyes, I'm not sure those are just cigarettes...)